# Query regarding nature of a statement. On-topic here?

Tags: discussion

Below is the question is asked [here](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/751/6102) (with a last two questions removed) and would like to ask the same for this site:

> Question regarding a statement one reads somewhere and is not sure as
>   to what meaning to derive from it, or has derived a meaning from it
>   but would like to be sure whether the derivation is correct or not.
>
> Are questions of this nature welcome here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of question is probably not on-topic here unless it addresses a general grammar or syntax question, or if it is asking about meaning in specific and perhaps unusual context. Questions about interpretation of literature or proofreading the Internet, for instance, are not on-topic.

You have enough rep that you could ask in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage).